# aframe 360 video only displays first time. Then, only sound

Tags: html, video, aframe, webvr

I'm working on a tour in webvr and using a-frame to build it. I have a bizarre problem. I seem to be able to get aframe to play a video inside a videosphere and correctly display every second of it the first time I enter a new scene, but whenever I exit from it and try to enter it again, only the sound works as supposed. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong in the loading of the video or something

I'm collecting the path to the video from a json file in which I describe what each rooms contains (they may have interactable pins for 16:9 video, images and the sort, and also pins that simply load a new scene).
After loading the json, I set the source of the videosphere, name image360, as such:

```
document.getElementById("image360").setAttribute('src', "#" + jsonArray.zones[zoneID].locations[locationID].name);
```

I then play the video using the following code :

```
video = document.querySelector('#' + jsonArray.zones[zoneID].locations[locationID].name);
    video.muted = false;
    video.addEventListener("ended", videoEnded);
    video.play();
```

The event listener I add to the video takes care of taking the user back to the previous scene once the video ends, which I do using this code:

```
 //This function is called immediately after the end of a 360 video. Thus it first starts by obtaining the scene it should load after the end of the scene
    var thisEl = document.querySelector('#' + jsonArray.zones[zoneID].locations[locationID].name);
    var currentLocation = jsonArray.zones[zoneID].locations[locationID];
    var locationToReturnTo = currentLocation.locationToReturnTo;
    var zoneToReturnTo = currentLocation.zoneToReturnTo;
    //With the information obtained, the room is then loaded
    generateRoom(zoneToReturnTo, locationToReturnTo);
    //After loading the room, time to generate the correct pins
    generatePins(zoneToReturnTo, locationToReturnTo);
```

I'm truly at a loss here, and have no idea why this doesn't work. I should note that javascript and aframe are not my area of expertise at all, I just had to pick up this project after a former colleague of mine, who was working on it, left the company abruptly, so excuse me if I'm making a basic mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: doesn't explain the issue, but did you try `video.load();` instead of `video.play()` ?

Comment: I did, the video doesn't play if I simply call load. The thing that feels the strangest to me is that the sound keeps working and the video keeps ticking, because the event I add that is called when the video ends always runs, however, the image is always stuck and never updates.

Comment: `#image360` is a <video> asset or a <a-video>

Comment: #image360 is actually the videosphere entity, sorry, I should have cleared that up. I managed to find the issue though. It appears that aframe cant handle 360 videos playing more than once if they're added dynamically to the index. If I just hardcode the <video> into the index.html file and then change the videosphere source to point to it itworks as it's supposed to. I was adding it to the index file via reading from a json file though, hence why it wasn't working. I've exausted most other avenues I've looked into, I think I'll just hardcode it

Comment: The reason why i asked is because i remember a [buggy bug](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3615) showing up when changing sources directly (not through the `<a-assets>`)

Comment: Try changing the source of the `assets` element (check out my anwser), it may prevent you from hardcoding the video sources :)

Answer (score 0):

Switching videos directly on a entity may not work properly:

```
document.querySelector("a-video").setAttribute("src", "vid.mp4")
```

because of the current tmp `<video>` [handling](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3615).

---

You should try using the [assets management system](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/asset-management-system.html):

```
<a-assets>
  <video id="vid" src="derby.mp4"></video>
</a-assets>

<!-- Scene. -->
<a-plane src="#vid"></a-plane>
```

**JS**

```
(#vid).setAttribute("src", "newvid.mp4")
```